# Compare string value in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to compare string value in excel vba ? for example texbox1.text = A and textbox2.text = AAA, so texbox1.text < textbox2.text therefore msgbox will display A < AAA.  how to achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You know you can do something like `Msgbox textbox1.text & "<" & textbox2.text` -- but you will need to make some `If` statements or other conditional logic to display the proper sign (`<, >, or =`).

Comment: Basically what I want is to compare 2 textbox value. If texbox1 value is smaller than texbox2 then a message box will show texbox1 value is less than textbox value. I know how to compare them if there are integer value however in this case the value is string and can be in the range of A - ZZZ.

Comment: You can use the same logical operators on text strings, per my previous comment.  For example, `If textbox1.text < textboxt2.text Then ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are the textbox strings in reference to `Columns`?

If so, you just need one `If` statement to check the condition:

**Untested**

```
If Columns(textbox1.Text).Column < Columns(textbox2.Text).Column Then
    Msgbox "" & UCase(textbox1.Text) & "<" & UCase(textbox2.Text) & ""
End If
```

You'd need to add some error handling though to handle situations where the text didn't match a column reference.

Also, if this is in reference to columns, in Excel 2010 the maximum column is `XFD` or column number 16,384...